# Is there a UniObjects equivalent to the UniBASIC LOCATE?

Tags: uniobjects

I have looked at the documentation for UniObjects for Java and VB and do not see a way to search a UniDynArray without resorting to a loop.

Is that the intention you think to rely on the API language (i.e. Java)?

This is what I ended up doing in VBScript.

```
If InStr(daShipAlones.TextValue, sDocNum) = 0 Then 
    ....
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with your findings that there is no "UniObjects" way to search through a UniDynArray.

You can search without resulting to a loop (and in one line) by converting the UniDynArray to a string array and then using the language's IndexOf equivalent to retrieve the location of you search term. In C#/VB this can be done like so:

```
Array.IndexOf(myUniDynArray.StringValue.Split(UniConstants.FieldMarker), "searchterm")
```

Where `UniConstants.FieldMarker` is essentially an alias for `(char)254`